# mysql: want the case query to return as null or empty if match is not found

Tags: mysql

Expertz plz plz HELP :(

i have a relationship table

```
r_id    usera   userb   active
13       5         1      0
16       1         2      0
```

now i want to check if some other users are friends with id no 1 and give me other ids except 1

like for this query i expect the ans to be empty because the condition active=1 is not met

if the condition returns true than i would expect the result as 5,2

so i have formed this query

note:user_id keeps on changing depending upon the session

```
$user_id = 1
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN `usera`=$user_id 
        THEN `userb` 
        ELSE `usera` END  
FROM  `relationship`  
WHERE `usera`=$user_id 
    OR `userb`=$user_id and `active`='1'
```

now the problem is even if the conditon is not met(i.e active=1) it still gives me userb
i want the query to  return as empty or null

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some parentheses:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN `usera`=$user_id 
        THEN `userb` 
        ELSE `usera` END  
FROM  `relationship`  
WHERE `usera`=$user_id 
    OR (`userb`=$user_id and `active`='1')
```

or even this which is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN `usera`=$user_id 
        THEN `userb` 
        ELSE `usera` END  
FROM  `relationship`  
WHERE (`usera`=$user_id OR `userb`=$user_id) 
  and `active`='1'
```

Comment: Always good to have them, but they are unnecessary in this case (`and` binds tighter than `or`).

Comment: @KeithRandall I agree but without parentheses it will not know where to apply the `and` condition. See my edit, they are different queries based on the parentheses.

Comment: You had me until 'it will not know where to apply the `and` condition'.  That makes no sense, mysql knows exactly when to apply the `and` condition.  There are strict rules for operator precedence.  Yes, you will need the parentheses in your second sql (to make the `or` go first).

Comment: @KeithRandall you are right, my explanation is not the best.  It will know where to apply the `and` condition...however if you do not have parentheses the queries are different.

Comment: awesome sheesh thnx guys :D ur the best @bluefeet :)

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are wrong:

```
$user_id = 1
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN `usera`=$user_id 
        THEN `userb` 
        ELSE `usera` END  
FROM  `relationship`  
WHERE (`usera`=$user_id  OR `userb`=$user_id) and `active`='1'
```

You only seem to care about active users, but you were putting the condition only on the second part of the conditional expression.